# Eclipse: Android Device Chooser - Unknown Android 2.3.4 Device

Tags: android, debugging, eclipse-plugin

I have a Nexus One phone running Android 2.3.4. I am trying to build an application using the USB open accessory library. To do this I have selected Google APIs 10 as the Build Target. The  project is actually an application provided by Microchip that I know works on this device. I installed the APK of the application to the phone manually and it works. Now I want to be able to debug and modify the application.

When I press the Run button and it comes time to choose a platform. The Android Device Chooser window comes up with the following with the Nexus One plugged in:

[image: Android Device Chooser]

Any ideas?

Thanks,

EDIT: I working in a Linux development environment. Specifically Fedora 14.

Comment: You put your Nexus into debug mode?

Comment: correct. the Nexus is in debug mode

Comment: You do have 2.3.4 Android SDK installed?

Comment: @Alan there is no Android 2.3.4 SDK. See http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3.4.html

Comment: Obviously I haven't been working with 2.3.4 yet -- well good luck, I got nothing!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The solution was to create a udev rule for the device. See http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html#setting-up for how to setup a udev rule for your specific vendor device.

With the rule in place. Eclipse was able to launch and debug.

[image: device]

Answer (score 12):

Supposing you are on Linux:
Your device-node-permissions are very likely wrong. Check if this is true by issuing a:

```
adb kill-server
sudo adb start-server
adb devices
```

on your computer. This launches the adb-server as root. If this work, and it doesn't work if you leave out the `sudo`, you have a permission-problem.

The solution depends uppon your distribution and your installed versions check [this blog entry](http://www.juanantonio.info/blog/2011/01/07/permissions-on-ubuntu-to-develop-with-android-devices/) which explains how to generate a `udev` file for Ubuntu.

Comment: Correct on udev. I created a rule for my Google vendor and was able to launch a debug session. Realized this shortly after posting the question. Posted a solution above.

Answer (score 4):

It also might be that there is no USB vendor ID for the Nexus One where The Nexus One shows up as “?????????” in adb/Eclipse.  So if you want it to recognize then you have to follow these steps:

```
1.  Follow the instructions at  http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html
2.  Replace the vendor id of “0bb4″ with “18d1″ in /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules. 
    Or add another line that reads:
        SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666"
3. restart computer or just "sudo service udev restart"
```

Answer (score 2):

Copy this file in /etc/udev/rules.d/

and rename to "51-android.rules" and add permission chmod a+r

```
#/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

#Acer
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0502", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

#ASUS
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0b05", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

#Dell
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="413c", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

#Foxconn
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0489", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

#Garmin-Asus
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="091e", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

#Google
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

#HTC
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

#Huawei
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="12d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

#K-Touch
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="24e3", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

#KT Tech
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2116", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

#Kyocera
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0482", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

#Lenevo
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="17ef", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

#LG
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

#Motorola
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="22b8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

#NEC
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0409", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

#Nook
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2080", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

#Nvidia
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0955", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

#OTGV
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2257", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

#Pantech
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="10a9", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

#Pegatron
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1d4d", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

#Philips
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0471", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

#PMC-Sierra
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04da", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

#Qualcomm
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="05c6", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

#SK Telesys
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1f53", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

#Samsung
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

#Sharp
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04dd", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

#Sony
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="054c", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

#Sony Ericsson
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0fce", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

#Teleepoch
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2340", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

#Toshiba
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0930", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

#ZTE
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="19d2", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enter the sdk/platform-tools and run with su in Ubuntu.
Then kill and restart the adb service.

Now the devices name can be recognized.

Answer (score 1):

Tried all above none worked .. finally worked when I switch connected as from MTP to Camera(PTP).

Comment: Worked like charm!! then all other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
./adb kill-server &&
sudo ./adb devices
```

Answer (score -1):

Install this http://pdanet.co/

then reattach your device .... then it will ask you to accept some certificate or something like that ....press ok

**Its Done!** :D