# ADB shows Motorola Xoom as offline when connected

Tags: android, driver, adb, xoom, motorola-droid

I have a Wi-Fi Motorola Xoom that I am connecting via ADB for development. I am seeing an intermittent problem where the device (with ID number) shows up in the adb devices list, but will present as being offline.

The device and computer both show the tablet as being connected. I've tried a combination of rebooting each device and swapping USB ports, but the only thing that solves the issue is switching out the cable. Furthermore, a cable that I used yesterday doesn't work today -- I am having to use a previously non-functioning cable to connect.

Is this a driver issue? Device port issue? I have seen this issue with several versions of the Motorola drivers as well as the PdaNet drivers. I am currently using Motorola Mobile Drivers 4.7.1.

WARNING: this question referred to an older device and as such the answers may no longer be relevant to current ADB connection issues.

Comment: Refer this post. This may help you
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15975435/2798287

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I met the same problems like yours, and I found out that the USB cable has mal-functions in the PIN of head USB. So I switch to the new USB cable, it just works fine and detect device as online.

Comment: I have three cables that I switch between and each one works intermittently. Was that your experience? Which brand of cable have you found works best?

Comment: The two cables I have tested that work best is the Samsung Galaxy SII USB Cable and HTC Desire (Black & White models) Cable. These two gives me the best use. Well, my experiences on the job.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and switching from the USB port on the front of my machine to the port on the back made things work.  It could be related to a difference in port power or USB type.

Answer (score 0):

From XDA: nouvelle_adr http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2247471

I downloaded the adb version and it worked.

> When you connect a device running **Android 4.2.2 or higher** to your computer, **the system shows a dialog asking whether to accept an RSA key that allows debugging through this computer.**
>
> This security mechanism protects user devices because it ensures that USB debugging and other adb commands cannot be executed unless you're able to unlock the device and acknowledge the dialog. 
>   **This requires that you have adb version 1.0.31** (available with SDK Platform-tools r16.0.1 and higher) in order to debug on a device running Android 4.2.2 or higher.
>
> If you haven't this pop-up mesage in your device, there is the solution :
>
> 1) Install SDK in your PC
>   It may asks you to install JAVA, if so, do it.
>
> 2) make sure that your adb is 1.0.31 or upper, to know the version, tape : adb version in your commande window"