# Eclipse won't recognise android phone

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 that I would like to deploy my app to using eclipse. However the device simply does not appear on the list of devices to deploy to.

- I am using Windows 7 64-bit.
- The phone appears as a drive when plugged in, allowing me to transfer files to and from the device.
- The phone has *developer mode* and *USB debugging* switched on.
- In the Android SDK Manager, the `Google USB Driver` appears as *installed*.
- I have manually installed the usb driver located at `\extras\google\usb_driver\`.
- This same device has been recognised and deployed to on other computers.
- I have tried restarting the adb server in command prompt using `adb kill-server` and then typing `adb start-server`.
- I have tried restarting both the phone and the computer.

My deployment screen simply thinks there is no android device:

[image]

Any ideas? Is there perhaps something I am missing here that is required for my android device to be properly recognised by eclipse?

Comment: Restart your adb server, check if it's recognized by adb by running adb devices

Comment: @user1281750 Please explain :)

Comment: I had the same problem. I had forgotten to activate developer mode and activate usb debugging

Comment: @Shervin developer mode and usb debugging are both switched on.

Comment: When you do run as android application, it doesn't show your phone as an option? In your deployment screen, choose Always prompt to pick device

Comment: @Shervin The phone does not appear on the list. When I select `Always prompt to pick device` and try to deploy the application, it displays a dialog box saying `No compatible targets were found. Do you with to add a new Android Virtual Device?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need an OEM driver, not the google USB driver.  Some people say installing Samsung Kies (I think you'll need Samsung Kies 3 actually) gets you that driver for free.  Or you might try the Samsung site, as listed here:
http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

Personally, I tried both of those and a lot of other things before I finally got it working.  Of course it was all my fault.  I had forgotten to turn on USB debugging.  Reading your question made me realize that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From Android 4.2.2 ADB need RSA authentication. 
Make sure your device is not appeared as `offline` in the output of `adb devices`. 
If so, you need to update the latest driver and SDK, then re-plugin the cable. 
If there is a  `Allow USB debugging` window pops up in your phone, everything will go right.

Comment: I have updated to the latest driver. USB debugging is switched on. I'm not sure what you mean by `Make sure your device is not appeared as offline on adb devices`. What is that?

Comment: Just run the "adb devices" command, and check if your device is offline.This thread maybe helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993855/android-adb-device-offline-cant-issue-commands

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it helps to simply open the DDMS view. I don't know why it helps, but sometimes it just does. 
If you open DDMS and your device appears in the list in DDMS, it should then also appear in the list of devices for running the app, even if it wasn't there before opening the DDMS view.

Comment: Unfortunately the device does not appear in DDMS view. :(

Answer (score 0):

First Check

> Always prompt to pick device.

Then right click on your project and run as android application.
it will show your phone.
Try it.

Comment: This results in a dialog box saying `No compatible targets were found. Do you with to add a new Android Virtual Device?`

Answer (score 0):

I know this may not be possible for everyone, but I changed my USB cord and it worked. Don't really know why because the other one would charge my phone and say I was connected.