# ADB is not working with my phone. Even though its showing up in the list.

Tags: android, adb, alcatel-ot

So, I am running on a Brightspot (T-Mobile) Alcatel One Touch Fierce and Its registered on ADB just fine. Its not giving me any logs even though all the options are currently running for developer stuff.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Does the adb show your device as offline or online ?

Comment: Online - Which is why this is so puzzling.

Comment: Did your device ask for something like http://adbdriver.com/images/adb-rsa-key-fingerprint.jpg when you connected to your computer for the first time ?

Comment: I dont recall - is there a way to bring that back up? @ShivamVerma

Comment: Settings > Developer Options > Revoke USB Authorizations then Disconnect and Reconnect your phone.

Comment: That option is not actually showing up in my list.

Comment: @ShivamVerma - I did manage to get into android shell using adb and I manually looked at log cat in the file system so it is working its just not showing up in android studio.

Comment: If nothing else works, I guess you could use the terminal to access logcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly check if your device is getting listed by using the following command

```
adb devices
```

If yes, then also check if it is online. If no then try the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993855/android-adb-device-offline-cant-issue-commands). After that try to see the logs by issuing the proper command as given on the [logcat developer website](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html).

Comment: We are actually fleshing all of this out in the comments. ADB is online and the phone is coming up and it is compatible. Everything is in the green. Still not working.