# adb needs an upgraded sdk to work but cordova needs a downgraded sdk. How can I make both happy?

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator, windows-8.1

When I type `adb devices -l` this is the output:

```
$ adb devices -l
List of devices attached
VS9854G22b261d6        offline
```

I think that `VS9854G22b261d6` is my phone.  I had to install LG drivers before that would show up.

[It seems like the solution to that "offline" problem is to update the android sdk.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993855/android-adb-device-offline-cant-issue-commands)  But, cordova requires an older SDK (api version 19, right?)  So how can I make both `adb` and `cordova` happy?

I'm on Windows 8.1 and I have a Verizon LG G3 device.  I have enabled USB debugging on the device.  When I type `cordova run android` it starts the emulator and deploys to that.  I am expecting this to deploy onto my connected device instead of onto an emulator.  The "hello world" app deploys fine to the emulator, but I'm trying to deploy it to my device and I can't figure out why it's not even trying to do that.

When I type `cordova run android` this is the output:

```
...
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2 seconds
Built the following apk(s):
    C:\...\cordova\platforms\android\ant-build\CordovaApp-debug.apk
WARNING : No started emulators found, starting an emulator.
Waiting for emulator...
### Error: could not find emulator icon resource: android_icon_32.png
```

Comment: `adb` is not part of any API, it comes with platform tools. You can use the latest version of `adb` with any version of API: be it 21, 19 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I plugged into a different USB port and then it said "unauthorized".  I changed the USB connection to camera and then the device asked me to authorize it.  Then `adb devices` said "device" and `cordova run android` worked as expected.  Seems to be a ton of different solutions to the same problem.  This is all I needed.