# how to run eclipse indigo run sony mobile zr device (C5502)

Tags: android, adb, android-debug

How to run a program on your phone sony zr ،Personal computer with the Eclipse runtime , but knows it 's shown as offline while the phone is placed in debug mode

Comment: when connect to my pc show Device in target  offline  ! iam using eclips indiago

Comment: Try following commands: `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server`.

Comment: not worker the Unknown device

Comment: adb devices
List of devices attached
EP7347898S      offline

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe because you did not verified your PC on your phone.
First, unplug you device, open Developer Options, make sure "Android debugging" is turned on. Then select "Revoke USB debugging authorizations" and confirm.

Now plug your device in again, make sure its display is turned on. Now you should get a message that you must authorize your PC to get access on your phone.
That should work now.

You can also enable Wireless Android Debugging. Then you open a terminal/command line in your "sdk/platform-tools" and type "adb connect YOUR_IP" (or ./adb connect YOUR_IP under linux). Replace YOUR_IP with your phones IP which you can find on your phone settings under "About Phone" -> "Status".

In addition to that all: Why do you still work with eclipse? Switch to android studio, that's the new standard!

Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: Thank you for your response
I did all the steps, but the following error message is displayed  adb tcpip 5555
error: device offline

adb connect 192.168.0.4:5555
unable to connect to 192.168.0.4:5555:5555

Comment: Remove the :5555 and you don't need tcpip anymore. It is not necessary. just tipe adb connect XXX.XXX.X.XXX. That must be enough, otherwise it wont work. Still doesn't work?

 
Is your SDK updated? That is the last problem I know. Otherwise what you defently should do is switch to Android Studio, which probably fixes that issue because it's up to date! Good luck ;)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993855/android-adb-device-offline-cant-issue-commands

there you can find more infrormation ;)