# Ecilpse won't recognize my device after upgrading to Kitkat (4.4.2)

Tags: android, eclipse

I just upgraded my Android device to 4.4.2 and now Eclipse will not be able to choose a running Android device when I want to run my project. The Android Device Chooser shows my device up with a serial number as "????????????" and Target as "unknown" and State as "??". Additionally, I have enabled Developer Options with USB Debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what os are you using. i see that on my linux box with some devices. i normally kill adb and restart it as root and the devices shows up and works correctly. found that solution years ago on stack overflow or something like that. not sure if the same thing is needed with windows/osx. on linux, assuming adb is in your path:

```
$ killall adb
$ sudo adb devices
```

otherwise os you're trying to connect it to and the specific device information would probably be helpful in tracking it down.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few suggestions. Try them in this order until it works.

- Reboot the phone.
- Try turning off and then back on "USB Debugging" on your phone (in Developer Options probably).
- open cmd > go to the your Android SDK directory > type `cd platform-tools` > 
   type `./adb kill-server` > then finally type `./adb start-server`

References:

- [Eclipse - Target "unknown" in Android device chooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731375/eclipse-target-unknown-in-android-device-chooser)
- [Android device chooser - My device seems offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584976/android-device-chooser-my-device-seems-offline)

Answer (score 0):

The solution for my device after updating was to completely uninstall the device driver from device manager and reinstalling it. I am using windows and my mobile was shown as Android Phone and not as Nexus 7. Home it helps someone.