# Android Development with Device

Tags: android, eclipse, ide, adt, development-environment

I'm trying to use Eclipse with the ADT plug in enabled and whenever I try to load my test application onto my device I am prompted with the following screenshot [image]

How do I resolves this? I've tried adding driver from extra/google/usb_driver or whatever the directory is but still not working.

As well as this, as an extra aside, my layout view isn't rendering properly and I've no idea why (see below). Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

[image]

EDIT : as per BeardFaces suggestion I checked out his link, restarted it and now it recognizes it. My second problem still stands though in that I am left without a Graphical interface for what the layout will look like. I suspect this is due to something with my Java set up but am not sure.

Comment: do you have all the drivers for your device installed on you machine?

Comment: yes. i have installed these as well

Comment: Do you have usb debugging enabled on your phone?

Comment: Check out some of the answers from this question. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731375/eclipse-target-unknown-in-android-device-chooser

Comment: yes i do have usb debugging enabled on phone. 

@BeardFace i will mozy on over there now and check it out.

Answer (score 1):

BeardFaces reference solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening your XML layout file in eclipse with Open With->Layout Editor

Answer (score 1):

Several solutions for this:

- turn off and and Usb Debugging then on again.
- restart your device.
- Select "unknown" and Restart adb (it works for me).

for the rendering of the layout be sure to have installed the API 22 then

```
Refresh > Clean Project > Build Project!
```