# Eclipse show unknown device

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using `HCL ME U1` for testing my android application. But when i am trying to run my app on my device, it show unknown device and failed to install on device.
I follow [this question with accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7419964/1139398) but didn't find any device in device manager.
First time, when i connect device to my computer it show "Device driver successfully installed".
I am using windows 7 32 bit OS.
[image]

I didn't find any android device in device manager.
When i use cmd to find out device then it show in list.
I also enable USB Debugging and Unknown source in my hcl tablet.

Please give me some hint or reference.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of restarting the phone, go to task manager(windows) and kill the adb.exe process. After 10-15 secs, it will restart again by itself. It should detect your device then.

Answer (score 0):

Once I encountered this issue and none of the matters could solve my question except a simple trick. I turned off the phone, ejected the SD card, cleaned it with sth and then put it back into the phone.

After turning on the phone, everything was alright. You have other options too:

- Connecting your phone to pc while phone is connected to internet (to update its usb drive)
- Updating your ADB driver from device manager (while phone is connected to pc)
- Some USB cables don't have debug ability. Be sure of using a proper one.

Answer (score 0):

I recently solved a similar problem in Ubuntu by updating my Android SDK.  A year ago, I also remember I had great difficulty getting a different phone to connect to Windows.  I remember that, despite receiving the  "Device driver successfully installed" message, I had to manually install the [usb driver](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html) from the SDK Tools Manager.

You might also try "adb devices" to see if your device shows up there.  I would expect it to be in the Windows device manager of adb can see it.  You mentioned there were no Android devices in Device Manager: check for other unkown devices it might show up as.  I believe mine showed up as USB Mass Storage before updating the drivers.  An alternate guide to doing so can be found [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1631663).